# Facebook API get event formatted (html) description

Tags: facebook, api

I know how to get event description with Facebook API, but it returns plain string type. So maybe there is way how to get formatted description? With new lines, paragraphs, links and so on.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/event